# Scroll event is not binding to a html element after adding ng-switch in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am facing a strange bug in my code which I am not able to understand, May be scope issue,
event binding at wrong time, not sure.

Here is the scenario, I have the below partial.

```
<ul class="items">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

In the directive defined, in link: method, I bind scroll event to <ul> and it works.
i.e.

```
$(".items").bind("scroll", function(){
  console.log("scrolling...")
});
```

After  adding ng-switch,

```
<ng-switch on="show">
  <ul class="items" ng-switch-when="true">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>

 <ul class="another_items" ng-switch-when="false">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
 </ul>
</ng-switch>
```

In the controller, same code of binding scroll event no longer works,
I tried adding class to ng-switch and tried binding scroll event, but was not successful.
I tried adding a div and adding ng-switch as a directive, but with no success.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the code of the directive?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your bind event is being called slightly before the DOM is ready, so instead you can use the element parameter of the link function to add the event directly to your existing element.

```
replace: false,
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  element.scroll(function() {
    console.log("scrolling...");
  });
}
```